# Multiselect box keep database values as selected Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select

I am using the multi-select box as follows, where I want to keep old values as selected in edit mode.

```
{!!Form::select('team_id[]',$teams , old('team_id[]') , array('class'=>'custom-select', 'id'=>'team_id', 'multiple'=>true)) !!}
```

Below is my controller code.

```
$teams = Teams::select('team_name', 'id as team_id')
            ->where('team_status_id', 1)
            ->pluck('team_name', 'team_id');
        $teams->prepend('Select Teams', 0);
```

I have 2 tables. One is **teams** table, which contains the name of all teams. Other is **team_applied** table which contains team_id and survey_id. In add form, I want to display all team name in the multi-select box, and in edit mode, I want to show all team ids in team_applied table as selected along with other unselected team names.

Below is teams table:

[image: teams table]

Below is team_applied table:

[image: team_applied]

Here is my select box which I need values as selected:

[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

For showing multiple item selected at the time of edit, try something like this:

```
Form::select('size[]',['L' => 'Large', 'M' => 'Medium', 'S' => 'Small'], ['S', 'M'], ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control']);
// here ['S', 'M'] is the array that we have to show selected
```

[Reference](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists)